# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, user-interface, uikit

I've got a trouble with UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.footerCommentActivity = self.commentActivity;
    self.footerNewsActivity = self.newsActivity;

    [self.otherNews setTableFooterView:nil];
    [self.commentTableView setTableFooterView:nil];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html style='-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;'><head><style>p {margin:0px 0px 10px;padding:0;}</style></head><body style='background-color:transparent;padding:0;margin:0;'>%@</body></html>", self.postContentText];
    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html style='-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;'><head><style>p {margin:0px 0px 10px;padding:0;}</style></head><body style='background-color:transparent;padding:0;margin:0;-webkit-column-count:2;'>%@</body></html>", self.postContentText];
    }
    [self.postContent loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];




    self.loadMoreComments = false;
    self.loadMoreNews = false;
}
```

update code no 2: 
Ive changed the code into viewDidAppear function, but it still crashed

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    sharedData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.otherNewsArray];

    for (int i =0; i < tempArray.count; i++) {
        Post *otherNewsPost = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if (otherNewsPost.postID == self.postID) {
            [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }
    self.otherNewsArrayWithoutCurrentPost = [tempArray copy];


    //update height of main image, text, video.
    NSLog(@"post image: %@",self.postImageName);

    if (self.postImageName == nil) {
        self.postImage.image = nil;
        CGRect imageFrame = self.postImage.frame;
        imageFrame.size.height = 0.0f;
        self.postImage.frame = imageFrame;

        CGRect f = self.postContent.frame;
        f.origin.x = 0; // new x
        f.origin.y = 0; // new y
        self.postContent.frame = f;

    } else {

        [self.postImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.postImageName]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"postimage-placeholder"]];


//        self.postImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.postImageName];
    }
    NSString *htmlString = @"";
    if (self.columns == false) {
        htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html style='-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;'><head><style>p {margin:0px 0px 10px;padding:0;}</style></head><body style='background-color:transparent;padding:0;margin:0;'>%@</body></html>", self.postContentText];
        [self.postContent loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    } else {
        htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html style='-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;'><head><style>p {margin:0px 0px 10px;padding:0;}</style></head><body style='background-color:transparent;padding:0;margin:0;-webkit-column-count:2;'>%@</body></html>", self.postContentText];
        [self.postContent loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    }
    [self.commentTableView reloadData];
    [self.otherNews reloadData];

    if (self.otherNews.hidden) {
        [self adjustViewHeightForTable:self.commentTableView];
    } else {
        [self adjustViewHeightForTable:self.otherNews];
    }

    [self markAsRead];

    [self loadPost];
}
```

when my app start and I start login with app, it getting crashed *I'm using ipad simulator here*

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Session status]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8889890'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: then it is not really about the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() function, right? Can you try to add a new exception breakpoint to be thrown on all exceptions, so that we can see on which line the app crashes?

Comment: thank you, I've got the problem now. really I'm so glad that you told me to add breakpoint. Thank you very much

Comment: I am glad I can help in one way or another.